# Elasticsearch fix date field value. (change field value from int to string)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I used python ship data from mongodb to elasticsearch.

There is a timestamp field named `update_time`, mapping like:

```
    "update_time" : {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
    },
```

`epoch_millis`  is used for timestamp.

After everything done, I used `range` to query doc in date range. But nothing return. After some researching, I thought the problem was: python timestamp `int(time.time())` is 10 digit, but it is 13 digit in elasticsearch , [official example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) :

> PUT my_index/my_type/2?timestamp=1420070400000.

so I tried to update the update_time field by multiple 1000:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.update_time=ctx._source.update_time*1000"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I found all `update_time` become minus. Then I come up with that Java int type is `pow(2,32) -1` , much lower than `1420070400000`. So I guess timestamp field should not be int ?

Then I want to update the field value from int to string(I don't want ot change field mapping type, I know change mapping type need reindex, but here only need change value )

But I can't figure out what script I can use, official script document not mention about this

Comment: You need to change your mapping and set the type to `long` instead of `int`. You cannot change that with a script.

Comment: @Val The mapping is date type,  not int type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know groovy was a lauguage and thought it only used for math method because ES doc only wrote about that.

The sulotion is simple, just convert int to long.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/my_index/_update_by_query -d '
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.update_time=(long)ctx._source.update_time*1000"
  }
}'
```